# how can i force locale on Datepickerdialog android

Tags: java, android

I have a datepickerdialog in android . When I switch the language of the application to arabic mode , the datepicker locale changes to arabic.

Is there any way to force the datepicker to stay in english regardless the application locale ? The problem is that when i select a date , it reaches in the code as an arabic language date , which ofcourse causes an exception during parsing .

any ideas?

EDIT

```
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
{
    /*SET THE DATE IN THE TEXTBOX HERE*/
    Time chosenDate = new Time();
    chosenDate.set(dayOfMonth, monthOfYear, year);
    long dtDob = chosenDate.toMillis(true);
    CharSequence strDate = DateFormat.format("MMMM dd, yyyy", dtDob);
    //  Toast.makeText(TawajidiDetails.this,
    //                     "Date picked: " + strDate, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    selectedDateTo=String.valueOf(year)+"-"+String.valueOf(monthOfYear+1)+"-"+String.valueOf(dayOfMonth);
    toDate.setText(strDate);
}
```

I just noticed that CharSequence strDate = DateFormat.format("MMMM dd, yyyy", dtDob); is the statement which creates an arabic representation of date in strDate.

Is there a way in which DateFormat.format , formats the date to the english locale?

Comment: What do you mean _"reaches the code as an arabic language date"_?  I would expect that you get a `Date` or `Calendar` object from the date picker.  Failed that, you get individual numbers for day, month and year.

Comment: @AleksG thank you for the response . I just took your pointer and really saw what was going on OnDateSet callback . Please see my edit

Comment: But why are you formatting the date into a string if you then need to parse it again?  Why not just use it as the `Time` object?

Comment: @AleksG I am afraid I dont understand your argument . I actually need the date on the textview. So I can't use the Time object because I would like to display the date as "MMMM dd,yyyy" inside the textview .

Comment: I don't understand why you need to change the datepicker to English.  You can create your own SimpleDateFormat object and format the date in whichever way you need.

Comment: did you find the solution? I am also into the same situation.